# Как сделать запрос к mongodb для фильтрации по типу поля

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

У меня в базе есть поле. Общая структура этого поля это Array с объектами (список словарей). Но так же там есть записи где это поле просто словарь. Мне нужно выловить эти записи. Я пробовал так

```
{$and: [{'educations':{$type :'object'}}, {educations: {$ne: {$type: 'array'}}}]}


{educations:'object'}
```

Но мне это не помогло. Как мне отфильтровать по типу поля?

Answer (score 0):

Правильный запрос выглядит так:

```
{educations:{$not: {$type: "array"}}}
```